# (node:11254) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to query my Firebase database on NodeJS, I have

```
var admin          = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require('/path/app-firebase-adminsdk-bs45c-5a33370488.json');

var firebase       = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com/"
});

var fcmToken = "";

var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {

    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

        if(phone == '9786733361'){
            fcmToken = data[i].fcmToken
        }
    }

    console.log(fcmToken);

});
```

I ran `node database.js`

and kept getting

```
(node:11254) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null          
(node:11254) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: what is `console.log(data);` giving you?

Comment: @PeterHaddad : the first give `null`

Comment: Yes that's why length is undefined, please share your database

Comment: snapshot.val() returns a promise, you have to await it or use .then to get the value. an unresolved promise is undefined that's what prompts the error when you try to get the attribute length

Answer (score 1):

**DataSnapshot**'s val() can be null, meaning that [the object is empty](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val).

Hence your call for `data.length` will fail since you're trying to call that on `undefined` / `null`.

At this point it's hard to make assumptions about the data stored online, but you should double check the event you're listening for in `once` is indeed there.